# Getting customized Bitly links' analytics (for a particular user)

Tags: analytics, tracking, url-shortener

I had this pressing requirement. We are using bitly as the url-shortening and links analysis part for our project, and we were facing this requirement of being able to view analytics(as shown in bitly dashboard) for only user having 'a'/'one of the' particular username(s).

Do you know a way if bitly supports this.

so my link - bit.ly/xyxx

is clicked by user 'A' group users 10 times and by 'B' group users 5 times.

right now I can view the analytics for all the clicks (A + B user groups) for a single particular link.

I want to be able to view the bitly analytics for the 'A' group users
and 
for the 'B' group users separately. Do you now of any way bitly can let me achieve this using their dev API ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to create two unique links and send them to groups A and B separately. Our API does not allow you to distinguish individual users clicking through a given link.

If you use Google Analytics-style utm parameters to create two unique links pointing to the same place, all the clicks will also be rolled up into the same aggregate count for that URL.

Comment: Thanks James !! I think I can also post the links as different users by creating seperate accounts and handover the same to A and B groups, If I follow what you said - Do I have any choice to see only A's links on the dashboard on bitly dashboard ?